# Getting unexpected expression error from NSPredicate

Tags: ios, swift, nspredicate, ckquery

I have the following code:

```
let pred = NSPredicate(format: "content IN %@ AND (tallied == 0 OR comment != '')", arr)
let query = CKQuery(recordType: "Rating", predicate: pred)
```

Which throws *Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'CKException', reason: 'Unexpected expression: tallied == 0 OR comment != ""'*

But when I try

```
"content IN %@ AND (tallied == 0)"
```

it works fine, same with

```
"content IN %@ AND (comment != '')"
```

But I need to be able to query all records that have tallied == 0 OR comment != ''. How do I structure this?

Comment: According to the CKQuery documentation, OR is not one of the allowed predicate operators. I think you'll need to do two separate queries, and combine the results.

Answer (score 1):

The CKQuery not supported for OR:
https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/CloudKit/Reference/CKQuery_class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014043-CH1-SW8